# Переписать цикл FOR на WHILE

Tags: javascript

Задача:

> В цикле `for` всегда задают строгое количество итераций. Перепиши код из
> предыдущего урока, применяя `while`. Вспомни условие задачи: возвести
> двойку в степень, которую задал пользователь, но не более, чем в
> восьмую степень. Избавься от конструкции `break`. Не забудь увеличить i
> на 1 внутри цикла.

Было так:

```
let power = prompt('Укажи степень');
power = Number(power);
let result = 1;
// перепиши с помощью while
for (let i = 1; i <= power; i++) {
    if (i > 8) {
        break;
    }
    result = result * 2;
}
alert(result);
```

Переписал вот так:

```
let power = prompt('Укажи степень');
power = Number(power);
let result = 1;
let i = 1;
// перепиши с помощью while
while (i < 8) { 
  i++
}
{
    result = result * 2;
}
alert(result);
```

Ругается: "Переменной `result` присваивается неверное выражение".
Поясните что не так пожалуйста.

Comment: `{ result = result * 2; }` --- эта строчка лежит за циклом, а не внутри

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ругается "неверный результат выполнения при степени 8"

Comment: Мы не знаем что вы делаете и кто ругается

Comment: видимо 8 должно входить в результат.. а сейчас не входит

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант...

```
let power = prompt('Укажи степень');
power = Number(power);
let result = 1;
let i = 0;
// перепиши с помощью while
while (i < power && i++ < 8) { 
    result *= 2;
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Ничего не понимаю... Что вы там написали? Можете написать объяснение к коду?

Comment: Что именно не понятно?
Там только условие цикла и присваивание с умножением...

Comment: Уже поздно :), вы убрали проверку на существование `i`

Comment: Ясно... Я переборщил.

Comment: Можно кстати сделать так: `let power = Number(promt('Укажи степень'))` :), вам также по моему мнению, следует объяснить что это за оператор такой: `*=`.

Comment: Про такие операторы все описано в учебниках... 

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#операторы_присваивания

Comment: Я знаю про этот оператор :). Посмотрите в вопрос тс'а, там такой оператор не используется, соответственно тс про него не знает и что это значит? Это значит что вам нужно объяснить что это за оператор вкратце и оставить ссылку на документацию.

Comment: Ясно, учту на будущее.

Comment: А почему "на будущее"? Почему не начать с настоящего?